# Adding a dot for for currency in each 3 digits numbers

Tags: javascript

I have a code where it would give a dot for every 3 digit numbers lke snippet below

```js
function convertToRupiah(angka)
{
     var rupiah = '';    
     var angkarev = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
      
     for(var i = 0; i < angkarev.length; i++) 
         if(i%3 == 0) rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3)+'.';
      
     return rupiah.split('',rupiah.length-1).reverse().join('');
}
  
function showkerugian(str)
{
    // var tindak_lanjut = 
    $('#nilai_tindak_lanjut').val().replace(".", "").replace(".", "");
    var temuan = str.replace(".", "").replace(".", "");
    // var total = temuan-tindak_lanjut;

    $('#nilai_potensi_kerugian').val(convertToRupiah(temuan));
};
    
$('input#nilai_temuan').on('keyup focusin focusout ', (function(event) 
    {
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

        // format number
        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
            return value
                .replace(/\D/g, "")
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
        });
    })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput="showkerugian(this.value)" class="form-control nominal" id="nilai_temuan" name="nilai_temuan">
<input type="text" class="form-control nominal" name="nilai_potensi_kerugian" id="nilai_potensi_kerugian" readonly>
```

But the input text with id `nilai_potensi_kerugian` always error when the number digit were reached Billion (ex. 10.000.000.000). What could go wrong with my code ?

Comment: you have two inputs - > nilai_temuan and nilai_potensi_kerugian.
What do you want the input in nilai_potensi_kerugian be like?? Same as  nilai_temuan ?? Then why don't  you just copy the same to next input?? Am I clear??

Comment: @spirit yes that's true..but i have some other calculation for my web apps other than this, so i have to made the function like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inside your `showkerugian` function:

> `var temuan = str.replace(".", "").replace(".", "");`

Previous statement only replace up to two `.` in your `str` variable.
Therefore, numbers which requires more than two dots are not reset correctly. Read more about [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Check the problem and a possible solution using a `RegExp` as a pattern in the `replace` function:

```js
console.log('10.000.000.000'.replace('.', '').replace('.', ''));
// -> 10000000.000

console.log('10.000.000.000'.replace(/\./g, ''));
// -> 10000000000
```

The following includes the fix in your snippet:

```js
function convertToRupiah(angka){
    var rupiah = '';    
    var angkarev = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
      
    for(var i = 0; i < angkarev.length; i++) 
        if(i%3 == 0) rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3)+'.';
      
    return rupiah.split('',rupiah.length-1).reverse().join('');
}
  
function showkerugian(str) {
      var temuan = str.replace(/\./g, ""); // update pattern to regex in order to replace all `.` occurrences

      $('#nilai_potensi_kerugian').val(convertToRupiah(temuan));
};
    
$('input#nilai_temuan') .on('keyup focusin focusout ', function(event) {
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
              .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput="showkerugian(this.value)" class="form-control nominal" id="nilai_temuan" name="nilai_temuan">
<input type="text" class="form-control nominal" name="nilai_potensi_kerugian" id="nilai_potensi_kerugian" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `convertToRupiah` seems fine, BUT your `showkerugian()` is feeding wrong `angka` into `convertToRupiah`.

Let's review **your code**:

```js
function convertToRupiah(angka)
  {
console.log(angka) // I added this to log what is fed into the function
      var rupiah = '';    
      var angkarev = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
      
      for(var i = 0; i < angkarev.length; i++) 
        if(i%3 == 0) rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3)+'.';
      
      return rupiah.split('',rupiah.length-1).reverse().join('');
  
  }
  
   function showkerugian(str)
    {
      // var tindak_lanjut = $('#nilai_tindak_lanjut').val().replace(".", "").replace(".", "");
      var temuan = str.replace(".", "").replace(".", "");
      // var total = temuan-tindak_lanjut;

      $('#nilai_potensi_kerugian').val(convertToRupiah(temuan));
    };
    
    $('input#nilai_temuan').on('keyup focusin focusout ', (function(event) 
                {
              if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

              // format number
              $(this).val(function(index, value) {
                return value
                .replace(/\D/g, "")
                .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
                ;
              });
            })
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput="showkerugian(this.value)" class="form-control nominal" id="nilai_temuan" name="nilai_temuan">
 <input type="text" class="form-control nominal" name="nilai_potensi_kerugian" id="nilai_potensi_kerugian" readonly>
```

See the problem? Your code only removes the first 2 occurrence of `.`.

To fix the problem, I changed the line

```
var temuan = str.replace(".", "").replace(".", "");
```

into

```
var temuan = str.replace(/\./g, "");
```

which will remove ALL occurrence of `.` due to `RegExp`'s `g` flag

```js
function convertToRupiah(angka) {
  var rupiah = '';
  console.log(angka)
  var angkarev = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
  for (var i = 0; i < angkarev.length; i++) {
    if (i%3 == 0) {
      rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3)+'.';
    }
  }
  return rupiah.split('',rupiah.length-1).reverse().join('');
}
  
function showkerugian(str) {
  var temuan = str.replace(/\./g, "");
  $('#nilai_potensi_kerugian').val(convertToRupiah(temuan));
}
    
$('input#nilai_temuan').on('keyup focusin focusout ', (function(event) {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
    });
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput="showkerugian(this.value)" class="form-control nominal" id="nilai_temuan" name="nilai_temuan">
 <input type="text" class="form-control nominal" name="nilai_potensi_kerugian" id="nilai_potensi_kerugian" readonly>
```